# Compare similarity of two java files in Python

Tags: java, python

I want to be able to compare a number of files (at most 30) against each other in order to find some sort of degree of similarity. It wouldn't need to be perfect I just want some sort of red flag if two files are unusually similar. What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: Building a cheating detector? I think there are existing services for that.

Comment: Define "*similar*" and "*unusually similar*".

Comment: did you take a look at the [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Regular Expressions (commonly known as regex: [python regex docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)). Using grouping, you could find variable and function names, unique lines of code (lines that aren't whitespace or comments), etc.

However, creating a system that is smart enough to be able to detect similarities on its own can be very difficult. If you had some way of getting a number between 0 and 1 of two files and their similarities, you could test it against a high threshold. Anything over the threshold (say for example, 0.97) could be considered suspicious.

Besides looking at the physical code, you could also observe code density in the files. Imagine if you printed out a page of code and turned it 90 degrees. You essentially get a graph of the number of lines on each file. Using that, you can observe where there are peaks and valleys to see where the code is more or less dense. Two similar files may have the same or very close code densities. Also, using this method you don't have to worry about looking for variable or function names that are the same as you aren't so much looking at the code itself but rather how it's organized

Answer (score 1):

Fleshing out @mgilson's comment, here's a very simple start:

```
def file_similarity(path1, path2):
    "Return float in [0., 1.] giving some measure of file similarity."
    import difflib
    with open(path1, "rb") as f1, open(path2, "rb") as f2:
        s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(
                lambda ch: ch in " \t",  # don't sync on blanks or tabs
                f1.read(),
                f2.read())
    return s.ratio()
```

Read the `SequenceMatcher` docs for more.  In particular, if you have many files to compare, it's much more efficient to reuse a `SequenceMatcher` object (see the `set_seq1()` and `set_seq2()` methods).  And if you're using a threshold, as the accepted answer suggested, see the `real_quick_ratio()` and `quick_ratio()` methods to slash the time more.

To get better results, I'd feed the files through a normalization transformation first, primarily to replace tab characters with spaces (tabs and spaces are as different to character comparison as, say, `'a'` and  `'/'`, but the distinction is invisible to the human eye).  Removing all-whitespace lines would probably help too.